# Django 1.6: How to pass value from a dropdown to another template page

Tags: python, html, django

I want to get the value of the dropdown field that user selects and use it on the next page to filter some profile listings, based on the dropdown selection.

I've this in my index.html page and would like the user to select a option in the dropdown, and hit submit and get redirected to doclistings.html page

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <form action="/doclistings/" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" id="select">
          <option><b>Choose a Speciality...</b></option>
          <option value ="Dermatologist">Dermatologist</option>
          <option value = "Dentist">Dentist</option>
          <option value = "ENT">Ear, Nose and Throat (ENT)</option>
          <option value = "Opthalmologist">Eye Doctor</option>
          <option value = "Psychiatrist">Psychiatrist</option>
          <option value = "Orthopedist">Orthopedist</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit" id="ss-submit">Find Doctors</button>
        </span>
      </div>
```

doclistings.html

```
{% for doc in doclist %}
            {% if doc.specialization == } # value from the last page
            <div class = "doctorrow">
            <h2><a href="/docprofile/{{doc.id}}/">{{doc.name}}</a></h2>
            <h3> {{doc.specialization}}</h3>           
            </div>
            </div>
       {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def index(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        selection = form.cleaned_data['value']

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/doclistings')
else:
    form = DropdownSelectionForm()

return render(request, 'meddy1/index.html')

@csrf_exempt
def doclistings(request):
    return render(request, 'meddy1/doclistings.html', {'doclist': Doctor.objects.all()})
```

forms.py

```
class DropdownSelectionForm(forms.Form): 
    selection = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: IMHO the [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Try POST and then use the posted values from `request` to render it in the next view. Here is the doc -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

**EDIT**
You can do either of the following -

1. Set the alldocs view as the `form action` in the form and set `form method` to `GET`. So when the form is posted you can have the values in `query string` of the alldocs view.
2. Use the index view and check whether the POST action is performed or not by checking request.method, then get the value from there and use `redirect` (from `django.shortcuts`) to redirect to your view with the value you need as parameters.

The way how you can check POST or GET, is documented in the doc that I referred earlier.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer? Should I use post in the index view and request to render in the alldocs view?

Comment: I think I've done step 2, but I'm still not sure how to get the value from the previous page. I'm very new to Django..